# UISegmentedControl to switch between UITableView and UIWebView in MonoTouch?

Tags: uiwebview, xamarin.ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that I am currently using for displaying of a UITableView. I need to add functionality to this controller so that the following is possible:

- By default a UITableView is displayed in the main content of the controller.
- A UISegmentedControl appears underneath the top navigation bar. This control contains two options.
- On selecting the second option in the UISegmentedControl a UIWebView is displayed in the main content of the controller. When displaying the UIWebView the UISegmentedControl is still visible.
- When selecting the first option in the UISegmentedControl the UITableView is displayed again.

Currently I have tried implementing this using the following code:

```
    this.TableView.TableHeaderView = MakeHeaderControl ();

    public UIToolbar MakeHeaderControl ()
    {
        try {
            var toolBar = new UIToolbar (new RectangleF (0, 0, TableView.Bounds.Size.Width, 41));
            toolBar.Items = null;

            var seg = new UISegmentedControl (new RectangleF (5, 4, TableView.Bounds.Size.Width - 10, 33));

            seg.InsertSegment ("First", 0, false);
            seg.InsertSegment ("Second", 1, false);

            seg.ControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyle.Bar;
            seg.SelectedSegment = 0;

            seg.ValueChanged += (sender, e) => {
                var web = new UIWebView (this.View.Frame);
                this.View = web;
                var req = new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl ("URL"));
                web.LoadRequest (req);
            };
            toolBar.Add (seg);
            return toolBar;
    }
```

The problems I am facing with this code is:

1. The UISegmentedControl scrolls with the UITableView.
2. The UISegmentedControl is not visible when the UIWebView is displayed.

How can I implement this functionality without the two problems above?

Comment: As you said that when you scrolls tableView, UISegmentedControl also scrolls. But instead of that you can set UISegmentedControl on the current Controller and set tableview below that UISegmentedControl. Likewise you can call webview and set it based on position.

Comment: Any chance of giving me an example of how to set the views below the UISegmentedControl? Thanks.